# Accesing variable of parent .then in child .then , nested promises, protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, angular-promise

How to access a variable from inside a child `.then` , the variable being defined inside a parent `.then`

As you might have guessed, I am new to javascript. I only know synchronous thinking.

I need a quick solution for now. I have read about nested pyramid of doom and chained promises but unable to wrap my head around it. I would really appreciate if you can give me a working code for now so that I can access `items[i]` variable inside a child `.then`

```
var options = element.all(by.xpath("//....."));

options.then(function(items){
   for(var i=0; i<items.length;i++){
      items[i].getAttribute("disabled").then(function(attr){
              if(attr){ // do something based on attr value
                  var option = items[i];    
                  // unable to access items => option is undefined
                  console.log(option); 
              }
          });
   }
});
```

Comment: Using let instead of var in your for loop should solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the attribute of all the elements at once, you can use

```
var disabledArray = element.all(by.xpath("some_xpath")).getAttribute("disabled");
disabledArray.then(function(disabledValues){
  console.log(disabledValues); // prints the array of attribute values [true, true, false, ...etc]
});
```

To filter the list of elements based on some condition, you can use

```
var disabledElements = element.all(by.xpath("some_xpath")).filter(function(ele) {
       return ele.getAttribute("disabled").then(function(isDisabled){
           return isDisabled === true;
        });
});
```